# Does Log4j 1.x Compatibility API have security vulnerabilities?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have an old project that has some jars that uses in runtime Log4j 1 classes and I cannot upgrade those deprecated jars or upgrade to Log4j2 because the deprecated library was built to use Log4j1. And version 1 is out of support according to Apache website:

> Please note that Log4j 1.x has reached end of life and is no longer supported. Vulnerabilities reported after August 2015 against Log4j 1.x were not checked and will not be fixed. Users should upgrade to Log4j 2 to obtain security fixes.

and I want to protect this application from security risks.

So I was wondering if I used the latest [Apache Log4j 1.x Compatibility API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api) along with latest [Apache Log4j API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api) and latest [Apache Log4j Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core).

Will that protect my application ? or the latest Apache Log4j 1.x Compatibility API still has security issues ?

Comment: It may be a bit obvious now, but for the benefit of readers, this is a consequence of not maintaining your software to use versions that are under security maintenance. You should plan to move to version 2 (but fix it in an easier way in the short term also if you can).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about CVE-2021-44228 , then yes it is not affecting 1.2.x versions of log4j.

Answer (score 0):

The [Log4j 1.x Compatibility API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#Log4j1.2Bridge) (`log4j-1.2-api.jar`) is **not** affected by any security vulnerability of Log4j 1.x.

However, if you use Log4j 2.x Core as backend for the Log4j 2.x API, you are affected by the vulnerabilities of Log4j 2.x Core. The last known one was fixed in version [2.17.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.17.0), published a couple of days after your question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not present in log4j version 1.*

Comment: Vulnerabilities reported after August 2015 against Log4j 1.x were not checked and will not be fixed. Users should upgrade to Log4j 2 to obtain security fixes.

Comment: I am talking about security risks in general in version 1